# Centrar verticalmente una imagen dentro de un div content-wrapper de AdminLte

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap, adminlte

estoy usando una plantilla AdminLte, que uso como layout. En la parte donde voy a meter el contenido está así:

```
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <section class="content">
                        @yield('content')
                </section>
                <!-- /.content -->
            </div>
```

En la vista donde tengo el contenido a desplegar tengo:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div>
        <img class="mx-auto my-auto d-block" src="{{ asset('dist/img/logo.png')}}" alt="logo" style="opacity: .2">
    </div>
@endsection
```

Al ejecutar, me aparece la imagen del logo centrado horizontalmente, pero verticalmente me aparece pegado al margen superior. He intentado varias formas, pero no logro que centre verticalmente. No logro entender cómo solucionarlo. Agradeceré una ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Usas bootstrap?

Comment: Sí, la plantilla AdminLte utiliza bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Considero que siguiendo la [doc. de bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/) puedes:

- Darle un display flex al contenedor, en este caso el div
- Mover al centro verticalmente con align-items dándole un valor de center
- Mover al centro horizontalmente con justify-content dándole un valor de center

Ejemplo:

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <img src="ruta_archivo" alt="" />
</div>
```

Edición

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ruta_del_css">
<style>
  img {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100px; /*esta medida es solo para construir el ejemplo*/
  }
  .container {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 200px; /*le estoy colocando un alto definido*/
  }
</style>
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <img src="ruta_archivo" alt="">
</div>
```

Generando un resultado como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Y te recomiendo le eches un vistazo a las características del [la propiedad `height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/height) y como se comporta

Comment: Gracias, pero sigue centrando horizontalmente, pero no verticalmente. Laí la documentación y probé otras variantes, pero no logra justificar verticalmente. Buscando información, di con algo en donde mencionan que en una situación similar, sí estaría centrando verticalmente, pero como el DIV padre se autoajusta al  hijo, el hijo al tratar de centrarse, se centra en función de su padre que está ajustado a él hijo. En este caso hablaban de hacer el body al 100%. Estoy tratando de encontrar la info nuevamente.

Comment: Entonces dale una altura definida al contenedor de la imagen para que los bordes superior e inferior de la imagen no rocen con este y se noten los 2 centrados @JuncoFuerte, de todos modos añado un ejemplo

Comment: @JuncoFuerte listo te agregué un ejemplo

Comment: Te agradezco tu ayuda y tiempo. Voy a seguir revisando lo de la propiedad height, pues ya estoy convencido de que el problema no es de las instrucciones de centrado vertical, sino que el problema guarda relación con el contenedor de todo esto, que al estar pegado, no centra nada. Muchas gracias y si encuentro la solución, la comparto por acá.

Comment: Aquí está la solución que aportó @Heru Purwito
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64962389/7154011